# Visual Studio 2019 broke Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2019

I have a next problem

after installation Visual Studio 2019 Community and latest version of SDK/WDK stopped load **driver projects** in Visual Studio 2015. Near the project writes - "not loaded". When i try to reload project it is error:

[image: error]

I found the same problem but with vs2017.
Visit https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/167978/side-by-side-vs2015-vs2017-installing-latest-wdk-f.html[/url].
I tried the solution with adding `<_NT_TARGET_VERSION>0x601</_NT_TARGET_VERSION>` in PropertyGroup. After that the project started to load but when i try to build it i have an error like this -https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/485290/error-msb4062-the-validatenttargetversion-task-cou.html

Maybe someone knows how to resolve conflict between vs2015 and vs2019? 
Thanks for help.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/167978/side-by-side-vs2015-vs2017-installing-latest-wdk-f.html